# html5 video = safari wants to download it all

Tags: html, video, safari

I have "performed" my frst venture into html5 video using the [video for everyone](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) and it works well in IE, Opera, Saf, Chrome, FF.

I have one small question - Safari (at least on my windows laptop) seems to want to download the whole darn video before it shows the first frame, or the buttons work - all the others stream it in the way I was expecting.

Has anyone got any ideas why - or more important how I get it to work more effectively!

Here's the code

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
<source src="http://www.visievoorisrael.nl/images/stories/jos01/video/rootsAndReflections002b.mp4video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> <!--Safari / iOS video    -->
<source src="http://www.visievoorisrael.nl/images/stories/jos01/video/rootsAndReflections002.theora.ogv" type="video/ogg" /> <!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  the video encoding. I had issues with this too. Some conversion tools do it for you, others don't.

You can run [qtindexswapper](http://renaun.com/blog/code/qtindexswapper/) on it to move the index of the video from the end of the file to the front.