# safari mac wont stream HTML5 video

Tags: macos, html, video, safari, html5-video

I am having a very frustrating issue with HTMl5 video and safari/mac.

I am using html5 video throughout the site where needed and it works/plays on every browsers bar safari on a mac (its fine on safari windows and chrome mac for example)

The videos dont stream and only play once the entire file is downloaded. At first I thought it may be to do with the index of the file being at the end and not the beginning (link [html5 video = safari wants to download it all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157063/html5-video-safari-wants-to-download-it-all)) so i tried qtindexswapper but when loading the MP4 into the program it said the MOOV/Index was in the correct position.

Anyone have any idea why safari mac has this issue?

A.

Comment: what format is the video, what do the tags you are specifying look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen HTML5 be very picky with videos. They may play fine in a player, but not play or maybe play with no audio once embedded. This is usually due to a video not properly created/formatted. In most cases, re-creating the file in a professional level program alleviates the issue.